# Ramda: How to use R.map with two arguments?

Tags: ramda.js

It works fine with a pair of array. I don't need to use Ramda in this example.

```
const addChild1 =  (x , y) => `${x}.addChild(${y}); ` 
const result1 = addChild(["containerA"], ["a1","a2", "a3"])

console.log(result1) //containerA.addChild(a1,a2,a3)
```

I couldn't make it work with 2d matrix of strings. I used `R.map`, but I get 'undefined' in the second argument.

```
const addChild2 =  R.map ((x , y) => `${x}.addChild(${y}); `) 
const result2 = addChild2(["containerA", "containerB", "containerC"], [["a1","a2", "a3"], ["b1","b2", "b3"], ["c1","c2", "c3"]])

console.log(result2) //["containerA.addChild(undefined); ","containerB.addChild(undefined); ","containerC.addChild(undefined); "]
```

How can I avoid the 'undefined'? Desirable output is the below :

**["containerA.addChild("a1","a2", "a3"); ","containerB.addChild("b1","b2", "b3"); ","containerC.addChild("c1","c2", "c3");"]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`R.map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) takes a functor (such as an array) as its second parameter, so in this case, only `["containerA", "containerB", "containerC"]` got in the loop

You should use [`R.zipWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) in this case instead of map

```js
const addChild2 = R.zipWith((x, y) => `${x}.addChild(${y}); `)
const result2 = addChild2(
  ["containerA", "containerB", "containerC"],
  [
    ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
    ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
    ["c1", "c2", "c3"],
  ]
)

console.log(result2)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `zipWith` is a good solution.  But I don't understand, "`map` takes string as second parameters".  [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a method that takes a callback and a `thisObject`.  The callback is supplied the item, its index and the whole array.  [`R.map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) is a function that takes a callback and a functor (such as an array).  That callback is supplied only the item.  No strings in sight.

Comment: @ScottSauyet my bad, it must be "takes array as second parameter". Thanks for correcting